# Why did this edit do nothing?

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, revisions-list

The [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/256549/revisions)  of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256549/days-missing-on-epic-legendy-badge-progress) shows that Revision 4 was made by a user who did not yet have full editing privileges. The edit was [approved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/39175) by another user with full editing privileges because s/he clicked "improve edit."

Strangely enough, Revision 5 does not appear in the revision history, nor is it displayed on the main post. There isn't even the text saying that an edit was removed during a grace period.

What happened to Revision 5?

Related: [Edit changed nothing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233843/edit-changed-nothing), but that is not for an approved edit case.

Comment: Some sort of trick, adding an invisible whitespace that was stripped server side, yet enough to satisfy the "Edit". Agree it's a bug that should be addressed, since it gives unfair power to 2K users. (binding review)

Comment: [Sorry](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3456931#3456931) :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard  I think I found the post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252623/i-improved-an-edit-but-did-i-actually. Should I vote to close as dupe?? I think it is a dupe...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ no doubt it's related but not sure same bug.

Comment: @Sha It's the same bug. It's *exactly* the same, this question is duplicate.