# Empty revision possibly after approving suggested edit by post owner

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, russian-stackoverflow

Looks like [there](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/713682/revisions) is a bug with a [new approving/rejecting suggested edits by post owner feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/339911) that leads to empty revision #3:

> [image: Empty revision]

The text says that "39 characters were deleted " is exactly the same count as actually deleted by revision #2.

Original post tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support) was made by @Qwertiy on ruSO.Meta: [А где содержимое правки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5824/176217)

Comment: I can't read Russian. Is this any different than [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233843/323179)?

Comment: @Laurel completely different. There are more than 40 minutes between edits and I can't imagine that OP could repeat completely same edit as previous editor.

Comment: I don't think it's related to OP actions. There is some ongoing bug allowing empty edits somehow, no idea how, but it's most likely the same root cause.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I can't accept it as duplicate, because only devs can know what is going on here. It looks related ofcourse, but in my case autogenerated message says about "39 characters" actually deleted on previous revision. I don't see same behaviour in NVZ's post.

Comment: "added 6 characters", or "removed 39 characters" really doesn't matter. It was an edit that was somehow "aborted", leaving empty revision.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd `+6 != (+13 + 4 + 40)`, but `-39 == -45 +6`

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd same results doesn't mean same root of issue!

Comment: I'm 99% sure it is which is enough for me to close as duplicate. In case I'm wrong SE developer who looks into it can easily reopen. (Or of course if other users here don't think like me, hence it won't get closed or get reopened by 5 others, which is totally legit)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd such bugs will never be fixed (or even researched) due to low priority, you should know! :) P.S. you stiil need 153 score point to be 100% sure for closing [tag:bug]s.

Comment: Oh I know, but I'm pretty sure being closed as dupe won't remove the bug from their list. We can monitor the other one, and in the slim case it's fixed, or gets official answer, post a comment asking the dev to take a look in "your" case as well.